# Cant delete cell in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using Xcode 5.1.1.

Created single view app for an iPhone. I'm testing in Xcode iOS simulator and everything works fine until I try to delete. Checked the code several times. In app "Edit" -> red "Minus" appears on every row then i'm pressing "Minus" and appears red "delete" button, that cant be pressed.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "AddViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize data;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"item1", @"item2", @"item3", nil];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source


-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView: (UITableView *) tableView {
    return 1;
}


-(NSInteger) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [data count];
}


-(UITableViewCell *) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    [[cell textLabel] setText:[data objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];

    return cell;
}

// Called after 'Save' is tapped on the AddViewController
- (IBAction) unwindToTableViewController: (UIStoryboardSegue *) sender {

    AddViewController *addViewController = (AddViewController *) [sender sourceViewController];
    NSString *text = [[addViewController textField] text];

    if(![text length] == 0 && ![[text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]] length] == 0) {

        // add it to the tap of the data source
        [data insertObject:text atIndex:0];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

        // insert it into tableView
        [[self tableView] beginUpdates];
        [[self tableView] insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        [[self tableView] endUpdates];
    }
}

- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [[self tableView] setEditing:editing animated:animated];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView comitEditingStyle: (UITableViewCellEditingStyle) editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [data removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Have you tried implementing the delegate protocol `canEditRowAtIndexPath` returning `YES`? See [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006941-CH3-SW26)

Comment: @sooper The default is that all rows are editable. Besides, how would the OP be able to see the delete button if the row wasn't editable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mispelled `commit` as `comit` in the method name. Not sure if this is *the* problem, but it is certainly *a* problem. It should be

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle: (UITableViewCellEditingStyle) editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [data removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You handle deletion, but you don't seem to enable it:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
```

Comment: added yours code to ViewController, breakpoint stops in your code three times for each hardcoded items but delete button still can't be pressed

Comment: This is the default. Besides, if this wasn't already in place, the OP would even be able to start the deletion.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you aren't Reloading Data after the deletion event.

On tap of the delete button, once you remove the data from the data source, call

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

and see if that works.

Comment: Question is not in why not updating. Button that must call handler cant be pressed, but should. So breakpoint is not stops on - `(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView comitEditingStyle: (UITableViewCellEditingStyle) editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath { ... }` cos button is not pressed

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with how you set your autoresizing mask - it's a weird behavior that presented itself on iOS 7.  Try calling this in your viewDidLoad function - `[self view].autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight` and this for your tableView - `[tableView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth]`.  I had the same issue with an app and this fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle: (UITableViewCellEditingStyle) editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [data removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
[self.tableView reloadData];}
```